# Replace a multiline string with the content of a file.txt

Tags: command-line, bash

I did a lot of research about this question but none of the solutions proposed has beed useful. I have two files, alpha (which is without extension, it's a openfoam dictionary) and beta.txt. I would replace a block of strings in alpha with the content of beta.txt. The content of alpha is this:

```
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Amin     0.3;
Bmin     0.1;
Cmin     0.4;
vertices
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
```

The content of beta is:

```
Amin     0.7;
Bmin     0.4;
Cmin     0.1;
vertices
```

I would **edit permanently** the file alpha (not only in the terminal) by substituting the block of beta in place of Amin ... vertices, Both numerical values of alpha and beta could change but the names "Amin" "Bmin" "Cmin" and "vertices" are constant.
I have tried perl as:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/Amin.*?vertices\n/`cat beta.txt`/se' alpha.txt
```

but it doesn't work. Note that there are n**ewlines, tabulations and semicolons**. Maybe they are not included. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? What errors or unexpected results do you get ?

Comment: It launches the command but nothing happens. I know that .* means all the characters but how can I include semicolons and tabulations that are all along the block?

Comment: Does `alpha.txt` have DOS-style (CRLF) line endings by any chance? that would cause your regex not to match

Comment: Actually, alpha is not a txt file but a dictionary of openfoam (blockMeshDict which has not extension) and I can't pass it as blockMeshDict.txt

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `file alpha.txt` (or `file blockMeshDict` as appropriate)

Comment: In the description you say: `alpha (which is without extension, it's a openfoam dictionary)` while in your command you have `alpha.txt` (with an extension). Which one is true?

After fixing this detail, I tried to reproduce and couldn't.  The example works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command *does* work for me.  Try running with `export LC_ALL=C` to remove any language issues.  And add `-w` to your `perl` command to turn on warnings.  Check that there is no whitespace after `vertices` in `alpha.txt`.  You may want to hexdump your input: `xxd alpha.txt` to check for invisible bytes that may be preventing your regex from matching, such as the carriage-returns that @steeldriver suggested.

Your test will also be easier if you *don't* run with `-i` (inplace replacement) but instead send your output to stdout, which you can redirect to a different file if you'd like.  That way you can more easily repeat your test if something goes wrong.  Once your command is working, you can add `-i` back.

Here's what I ran:

```
$ cat tt
cat alpha.txt
echo
export LC_ALL=C
perl -wp0e 's/Amin.*?vertices\n/`cat beta.txt`/se' alpha.txt
```

Here's my output

```
$ tt
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Amin     0.3;
Bmin     0.1;
Cmin     0.4;
vertices
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed

Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Amin     0.7;
Bmin     0.4;
Cmin     0.1;
vertices
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
Some text which must not be changed
```

By the way, you must have done *a lot* of research to come up with your command.  That command is a lot more advanced than I would expect from a first time questioner.

Comment: If you need to refer to the full path of a file, you must change the expression delimiter to a char other than `/`, for instance: `perl -wp0e 's#Amin.*?vertices\n#\`cat /path/to/beta.txt\`/se' alpha.txt`. I was naive to think `\`cat \`` would be out of perl reach.